# &amp; is displayed in some titles in 'settings' windows

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, i18n

At some point `&amp;` is not properly displayed as `&` in some system menus. How this can be cured?

Ubuntu Gnome  (look at window title).

[image: Screenshot attached]

Answer (score 0):

So the reason for that "broken" names was the fact the names were messed up in following way:
e.g.: `Mouse &amp; Touch­pad` was stored as this: `Mouse &amp;amp; Touch­pad` which visually represents `Mouse &amp; Touch­pad`.

Solution: manually edit names and remove `amp;` part with help of menu editor.